# MailChimp send email v3.0

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

The version 2.0 of MailChimp APIs has a campaign send API. However I don't find any similar API on v3.0. I do find an automation API where in I can start a workflow, however it appears from the documentation that workflows can't be created using APIs and can be created only using the GUI.
The requirement is to be able to send emails using MailChimp API. Please advise.

Answer (score 4):

It's now possible to both create and send a campaign through the V3.0 API.

See the 'Action' tab [here](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/campaigns/#)

You can send to a saved segment, but as far as I can tell, there's no way to create a saved segment via the API.

Comment: I've been looking through the documentation and I can't see anywhere to select a template and/or set a body, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You actually cannot send one on one email with APIv3.0. [Mandrill](http://www.mandrill.com/) now takes over for the transactional emails.

Answer (score 0):

It's not yet possible to edit or create campaigns in API v3.0. See the [API v3 roadmap](http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/article/3-roadmap).