# Sending email to lists via MailChimp API v3.0?

Tags: node.js, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

So it's not possible to create campaigns via MailChimp API v3.0 at this moment. But is it possible to send emails to lists/groups/segments via API v3.0? Or should I use API v2.0 for this functionality?

I have seen this one already: [MailChimp send email v3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30258610/mailchimp-send-email-v3-0)

Answer (score 1):

It's now possible to create and send a campaign through the V3.0 API.

See the [this page](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/campaigns/#)

You can send to a saved segment, but as far as I can tell, there's no way to create a saved segment via the API, or to send to any subset of the list members.